# how to evalute the value in excel, need help in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to populate the value in Column D.
I'm not getting the result using the formula. In the second row, instead of Arun I am getting kumar.

the formula i am using is `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10000,MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$10000,0)),A2)`

[image: New Updated excel]

Comment: The first issue seems to be you don't have unique values in column C, if you look for AAA then there are two possible results. ie Vinay or Arun.

Comment: yes thats true, but i have the report which have the same pattern, cannot change report.....its like rename mutiple times (Column B) but need the value of the first time creator

Comment: So which AAA will be the first time creator?

Comment: the first time creator will be  ROW 5 "ARUN"

Comment: My understanding does not seem to be the issue, how do you think you can get excel to choose between Vinay or Arun when they have the same code AAA

Comment: Solar, what if the value is changed , have updated the image in question

Answer (score 1):

So works as expected, this entered in cell D2

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$5,0))
```

The two errors are due to the blanks in B2 and B4. You can expand it as necessary.

[image]

Edit, added the iferror which puts **Name?** if there is an error:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$5,MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$5,0)),"Name?")
```

Comment: I am sorry. let me try to explain again,,,                                                                               
 ROW 5: "CF KC Secondary Recruiter" is assigned to Santosh,                         
 ROW 4: "CF KC Secondary Recruiter" changed to "CF - ESI - Secondary Recruiter"  by "LISA" but the creator is "Santosh" so i need value as "Santosh"                 ROW 3: "CF - ESI - Secondary Recruiter" Lisa agaiin changed to "CF KC Secondary Recruiter" but here also the original report belong to santosh , so I need the Value as "Santosh"..... The image is updated in main question

Comment: You need to sort out your identifying list and make sure that what you look for will give what you need - the example I gave you works based on the information originally supplied.